# How can I see R computation results in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: r, visual-studio

I'm using R, Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015 in my work. I can do calculations well in R console. But as I tried to make a Visual Studio project, I was unable to see the result. My code is the following:

```
print(2)
```

I tried to execute in interactive by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> but I can't see the result. So where do the result should appear?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I'm assuming you have R Tools from [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/rtvs/))

There ought to be an **R Interactive** window option under the **R Tools > Windows** menu:

[image: R Interactive screenshot]

Now the outputs of your R scripts (derived by highlighting some lines and pressing **Ctrl-Enter**) should go to that window:

[image: Output screenshot]

If that doesn't work, can you make sure you have the latest version of R Tools?  Version 1.0 only just came out recently...

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes I have R Tools from the given link. I tried to click the Interactive R option but I can't see any result.

Comment: Strange. How about a screenshot?

Comment: The results from your script appear in a separate window called "Interactive R". You can select it from R Tools menu.

Comment: Do you mean "R Interactive" instead of "Interactive R"? I tried to click the menu but nothing happened.

Comment: Yes "R Interactive". It's a window which is not only interactive, it shows the outputs when you do Ctrl-Enter from a script.

Comment: I've revamped my answer to include screenshots and other (hopefully helpful) tips